# Why am i getting exremely large numbers when adding elements of an array in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, addition

I was trying to add the first 4 numbers of my array. When I test it I always get the number "4201077" even though the first numbers 4 numbers are 1 2 3 and 4. When I try with different numbers starting, I get a slightly different variation such as "4201092".
What am I doing wrong?
code:

```
int main(){
   int a [10];
   int count;


   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i ++)
       cin >> a[i];

   int i = 0;
      while ( i < 4){
       count += a[i];
       i++;
      }

   cout << count;
    
}
```

Comment: If you compile with warnings enabled, the compiler's likely to tell you about similar problems.  For example, `g++ -Wall` or `clang -Wall`.

Comment: [Your compiler should have warned you](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/21e924967833b5d2)

Comment: Here is one way you could have gotten away with not having count initialized: `#include <numeric> ... int count; ... count = std::accumulate(a, a + 4, 0);`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You never initialize `count` to hold any value.  The line `count += a[i];` reads from `count` in order to add `a[i]` to that value.  In C++, reading from an uninitialized variable is *undefined behavior* in most cases, including this one.  Therefore, your program might do anything at all, including (but not limited to) printing the wrong result, crashing, or doing nothing at all.

```
// You have:
int count;

// Replace with:
int count = 0;
```

Always turn on all compiler warnings, and fix any that appear. Every compiler in common use will flag the line `count += a[i];` with a warning for reading from an uninitialized variable.  For example, gcc says this:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:14:14: warning: 'count' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
   14 |        count += a[i];
      |        ~~~~~~^~~~~~~
```

Comment: "Since count is signed, reading its value is technically undefined behavior." I'm pretty sure the bug would happen even if it was unsigned?

Comment: @Borgleader Already fixed. There was a reason for that verbiage but it's unimportant.

Comment: "*reading from an uninitialized variable is undefined behavior in most cases*" - Do you have an example where it isn't?

Comment: @Kevin For example if the type is of unsigned narrow character type. In that case value is simply unspecified, but no UB.

Comment: @eerorika Can you link to the standard where it says that? As far as I knew all access of uninitialized variables was undefined behavior. Jesper's answer has a link that seems to agree.

Comment: @Kevin It's right in the rule which says that this is UB in the first place. The rule continues something like "is undefined except ..." and then lists the cases where it isn't UB.

Comment: @Kevin N4713 [dcl.init]/12: _"If an indeterminate value is produced by an evaluation, the behavior is undefined except in the following cases: ..."_ And it goes on to list the allowed cases. Reading an uninitialized `unsigned char` and `std::byte` are such cases, but there are others.

Answer (score 3):

Reading uninitialized variables is UB : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub - which you do with `count += a[i];` when you have never initialized `count`.